# Sliding screen door rollers won't run into top track

Tags: doors, door-frame, sliding-glass-door

I am replacing my sliding screen door.

Old door used this [roller assembly](https://www.swisco.com/Screen-Door-Roller/pd/Patio-Sliding-Screen-Door-Replacement-Rollers/84-046?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIv57Eq-qe8wIV2_6zCh2HhQ3AEAQYASABEgLLE_D_BwE) and with correct adjustment both top and bottom rollers fitted into it's tracks and door opened and closed smoothly.

[New door I bought](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Grisham-Bronze-Aluminum-Frame-Sliding-Patio-Screen-Door-Common-36-in-x-80-in-Actual-36-in-x-80-75-in/1001600690) has adjustable expanders on top and bottom, with one inch metal rollers attached with rivet. Roller itself does not have any spring action (not adjustable), but you can adjust door height by adjusting expanders with screw.

[Installation manual for new door.](http://pdf.lowes.com/productdocuments/45d9dc89-26a9-407a-ac02-ad14452bd03c/43643779.pdf)

My problem: even with top and bottom expanders adjusted to achieve full height possible, top roller wheels don't reach/run over top track. It is just shy of around 1/4 inch. Because of this, when I open and close the screen door, it kind of wobbles/rattles and its side frame bangs with edge of sliding glass door when I close the door after opening it all the way.

Answer (score 2):

Either buy a door that better fits the opening or remove all the trim at the top of the door and shim it down with an extra 1x board.

This will reduce the vertical gap by ~3/4" causing the opening to now be within the adjustment range of the new door's hardware.

Answer (score -2):

I have the exact same problem. There’s no other solution shy of making the door 1/4 to 1/2” shorter. Gotta cut it.

Comment: Since the OP noted that his new door is already about 1/4" too short, how is cutting  1/4 - 1/2" off of it going to help? And is cutting an _aluminum_ door really an option?

Comment: This is the opposite problem; OP needs to **raise the threshold**. Which will then suck as a tripping hazard.

Comment: Or lower the top of the frame. Which is more work. Or bring the door back, take exact measurements of the doorway and the door being replaced, and buy one that fits.